# Sum concisely particular elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a variable stacks:

```
stacks = [[1, 2, 3], [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]]
```

From this I want to create another list of heights, where each height is the sum of the element at index 1 of each stack in stacks. In the example above, heights would be:

```
heights = [2, 7]
```

Where 2 is stacks[0][1] and 7 is stacks[1][0][1] + stacks[1][1][1]. Sorry if it was unclear before. How can I do this concisely using list comprehensions, map and `/` or reduce?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I don't understand your example. Could you spell out precisely where the 2 and 7 come from?

Comment: Where does [2,7] come from? Can you elaborate? Does your `stacks` actually a list of three lists?

Comment: Is there are extra pair of brackets in there?

Comment: Do you mean the element at index 1, rather than the 1st element?

Comment: Yes, I meant the element at index 1. I've edited my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `stacks` is exactly as you've described:

```
>>> stacks = [[1, 2, 3], [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]]
>>> wrapped = (s if isinstance(s[0], list) else [s] for s in stacks)
>>> total = [sum(x[1] for x in w) for w in wrapped]
>>> total
[2, 7]
```

It would be more natural, IMHO, if the elements of `stacks` were always lists of lists:

```
>>> stacks = [[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]]
>>> total = [sum(x[1] for x in w) for w in stacks]
>>> total
[2, 7]
```